# WAN/GAN IM application in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, instant-messaging

Hi I have started a project which connects to a database and creates/logs in a user at the moment i have a LAN messenger that works very well, and a FTP chat which is not exactly what i was hoping for.

my idea now is to create two tables in the database message 1 and message 2 both of which display the user who is sending and the message sent. and the program uses threading to connect and download the messages.

My question is, is there a better way of completing this task (if so could you send a link or two this way? or express your opinion).
and or any problems you guys/girls think i would run into. Cheers :D

If you require to see some code just ask and i'll edit the post thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although its easy on paper to do a chat application that uses a 'DB' as a backend/comms layer .. its not really the best approach. It will work... but with load, it may not be a very good approach.

Most chat clients uses a peer to peer connection, or even client server with the coding and implementation of a server that handles what happens with messages going/destined where ever.

If you really want to get low down and dirty, google for '**TCP chat application**' examples. If you want to operate a bit higher (not handle the really gritty low down mechanics), then look for some '**wcf chat**' examples.